# Deprecated: preg_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array

Tags: php, deprecation-warning, non-nullable

The following error appears at the top and bottom of my wordpress blog:

`Deprecated: preg_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated in /home//public_html/wp-includes/kses.php on line 1744`

The line in question is this:

```
$content = preg_replace( '/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F]/', '', $content );
```

How can I solve this?

I am just starting at web development, so I couldn't find success trying to change some code in the **kses.php** file. I managed to find it via file manager (cpanel, etc).  I tried reading tutorials related ([Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKcZO1UuJmI&t=1s&ab_channel=WordpressErrorFix)), but it didn´t work out.

Comment: You should check that `$content` is not empty before running it. It didn't hurt anything previously but it also wasn't accomplishing anything. Could change code to check that `$content` is not empty.

Comment: Maybe `$content = empty($content) ? '' : preg_replace( '/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F]/', '', $content );`